# Delta function? $\delta(x)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

In the following page: [Striking One of the Masses](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/pasp/Striking_One_Masses.html)

It opens with:

> Now let $f(t,x) = \delta(t)\delta(x-r) $

To describe a function of force $f$ at time time $t$ and location $x$

What is the meaning of the $\delta$ function here?  How is it defined?  What is it called?

Comment: A particular distribution (generalised function). In my opinion, the best way to consider it in a rigorous way

Answer (score 1):

It means [the Dirac delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta), but it's not a true function. In other words, the force happens at $t=0,\,x=r$, transferring some finite positive energy with finite positive [impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_(physics)). By dimensional analysis, there should be a proportionality constant equal to unit angular momentum.